# Working on my own machine but SIGABRT on SPOJ

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on the Next Palindrome problem on SPOJ http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/. My code works fine on my own machine, but SPOJ gives me SIGABRT. I'm using C++ 4.9.2

"A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.

Input

The first line contains integer t, the number of test cases. Integers K are given in the next t lines.

Output

For each K, output the smallest palindrome larger than K."

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

// turn 9 to 10
void round(vector<int> &input,int index) {
    int len = input.size();
    input[index] = 0;
    input[len-index-1] = 0;
    // if it is the first digit, add 1 in the front
    if (index == 0) {
        input.insert(input.begin(),1);
    }
    else {
        input[index-1] ++;
        input[len-index] ++;
    }
}

// find the next palindrome
int palin(vector<int> &input) {
    int len = input.size();
    bool large = true;
    bool small = true;
    bool eqal = true;

// if it is a single digit  
    if (len == 1) {
        if (input[0] == 9) {
            input[0] = 11;
        }
        else {
            input[0] ++;
        }
        return 1;
    }

// start from the one before the middle 
    int index = len / 2 - 1;
    while (index >= 0) {
    len = input.size();
    // the number supposed to be the same as input[index]
        int rfl = len-index-1;

        // keep record for if the updated number is smaller/equal to the original
        if (input[index] > input[rfl]) {small = false; eqal = false;}
        else if (input[index] < input[rfl]) {large = false; small = true; eqal = false;}
        else {small = false;}

        if (input[index] == 10) {round(input,index);}
        else {
            input[rfl] = input[index];
        }
        index --;
    };

// restart from the one before the middle
    index = (int)input.size() / 2 - 1;
// unless all digits on the left are larger than right/the more left digits are larger but some closer to the middle are smaller or equal, increase the number
    if (!large || small || eqal) {
        len = input.size();
        if (len % 2 == 1) { // odd
            if (input[index+1] == 9) {
                round(input,index+1);
            }
            else {input[index+1] ++;}   
        }
        else { // even
            if (input[index] == 9) {
                round(input,index);
            }
            else {
                input[index-1] ++; input[index + 1] ++;
            }
    }
        // go over the digits again to make sure it is a palindrome
        while (index >= 0) {
            if (input[index] == 10) {
                round(input,index);
            }
            input[input.size()-index-1] = input[index];
            index --;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int count; // how many numbers are there
    cin >> count;
    string buffer; // temporary to store each line of input
    for (int j=0;j<count;++j) {
        vector<int> number;
        cin >> buffer;
        if (cin.fail() || buffer.size() == 0) { // not a number or length==0
            return 1;
        }
        for (int k=0;k<(int)buffer.size();k++) {
            int temp = buffer[k] - '0'; // convert ASCII to int
            number.push_back(temp); // construct vector
        }
        palin(number);
        for (int i=0;i<(int)number.size();i++) {
            cout << number[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious He can't because he doesn't know what input SPOJ is feeding into his program to cause `SIGABRT`.

Comment: Your code isn't remotely the worst I've read, but it is dense and hard to read, and absolutely not clear or self-documenting, which is why you're running into this brick wall when it doesn't work. Your first step to helping yourself is to write readable, commented code to start with, and sweat the optimizations later (you have several things in your code that I suspect are optimizations but in practice just make it harder to read/debug). Any time you saved typing less has been dwarfed by the time you lost not being able to read what it *does*.

Comment: That said: What happens when `cin >> buffer` doesn't produce a number or is an empty string? What does `palin` do if `len == 0`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I add a few lines to include these possibilities but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, a brute force method would be inefficient, but would be pretty clear to code. Here, I just keep iterating through numbers until I find a palindrome, for each of the numbers:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7ac595d7c2cfa7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int count; // how many numbers are there
    std::cin >> count;
    std::string buffer;

    //two vectors to store output
    std::vector<long int> input;
    std::vector<long int> output;

    //take the inputs
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cin >> buffer;
        input.push_back(std::stoi(buffer));
        buffer.clear();
    }

    //check that we have the inputs
    for(auto it : input) {
        std::cout << it << std::endl;
    }

    //lambda to test for palindromes
    auto is_palindrome = [](long int n) {
        auto str = std::to_string(n);
        std::stack<char> stack;

        //Load each character into the stack
        for(auto it : str) {
           stack.push(it);
        }

        //Use the property of a stack to take out in a reverse order
        for(size_t i = 0; !stack.empty(); stack.pop()) {
            if (stack.top() != str[i])
                return false;
            else    
                ++i;
        }

        return true;
    };   

    //test for the palindromes; iterate
    for(auto it : input) {
        int n;
        for (n = it+1; ; ++n) {
            if(is_palindrome(n))
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }
        output.push_back(n);
    }

    //output the outputs
    for(auto it : output) {
        std::cout << "next palindrome: " << it << '\n';   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it will exceed the time limit.

Comment: If anything, you can use this to verify.